# Is it possible to turn off tap-to-click on and Asus Transformer Pad Infinity?

Tags: asus-transformer-infinity

I have an **Asus Transformer Infinity** and I'd like to turn off the tap-to-click feature on the keyboard dock's touchpad. Is this possible? I can't find a setting for it anywhere.